# What does this symbol mean in iTunes next to a song?

Tags: iphone, itunes

[image]

What does the open dotted circle to the left of the song name mean?  If you look at the highlighted song, it's the symbol below and to the left of "Equalizer".  It only appears when I plug in my iPhone to my computer.  I'm not able to play any songs with the open dotted circle next to them.